# What are the different code comment practices?

Tags: comments

Reading up on code commenting, there seems to be a general support for comments that do not explain anything the code itself can explain. All the sources (not that many, but a few still) I have looked up say that the comments should be explaining the code on a higher level of abstraction.

However, experts in the field I socialise and work with are supporting that more comments are better than not enough, that even if the comments explain something that the reader/coder can decipher from the code, there are different levels of this, and some people may decipher the code faster than others, so to be safe it would be better to comment code whose meaning is not painfully obvious; after all,

> "it will help you, as a coder, when you don't have to read the actual code, and can understand what a function does in English, rather than try and decipher code. Sometimes, it might even help writing the function out in comments and pseudocode before coding it; It will help as a constant reminder of what this function is **supposed** to do."

These two are quite different schools of thought as far as comments go. Which begs the question:

**What are the different schools of thought about code commenting, and what are the most popular (so as to avoid asking about the *best ones*, as that is subjective) sources I can read up on about code commenting practices?**

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly sharp write-up called [The Fine Art of Commenting](http://www.icsharpcode.net/TechNotes/Commenting20020413.pdf) over at ic#code. It's not perfect (Hungarian notation is horrible and should not be inflicted on developers), but it is still fairly interesting.

The author correctly notes that there are different things you may want to use comments for, and splits them into 3 classes:

- Documentary comments, for example copyright information, authorship, and version and changes information.
- Functional comments, which are your various "TODO" and "BUG" comments signaling out areas of code that may require further attention.
- Explanatory comments, which explain what the code does.

The third category is obviously the interesting one being discussed here. In my opinion, comments should describe why the code does why it does, and not how. For example, if your codes sorts a list, you should explain why the list has to be sorted in the first place - that the list is being sorted is (or should be) obvious from the code.

Finally, the most important thing about comments is that they are not compiled and have no effect on the behavior of the program. This may seem obvious. The consequence of this is that during the maintenance phase of the software, bugs in the code may be fixed, but the comments often remain unchanged, and may document behavior that is no longer observed. As wrong documentation is even less useful than non-existent documentation, it is very important to fix bugs in the comments as well as in the actual code.